# Bash shell code will not create zip file

Tags: bash, shell

Here is part of my bash sell script that is supposed to create an aa.zip tar file

```
#!/bin/sh
xx=`date "+%m-%d-%y"`
tar -cvf /mnt/backup/production1.$xx.tar --exclude=*.zip  /home/wvbadmin/production/*
split -b 2400m production1.$xx.tar production1.$xx.tar.
#zip tar files
zip production1.$xx.tar.aa.zip    production1.$xx.tar.aa
rm production1.$xx.tar.aa
zip production1.$xx.tar.ab.zip    production1.$xx.tar.ab
rm production1.$xx.tar.ab
```

Whenever I run this shell script, the aa.zip file is not created but the ab through az zip files are. What could be the reason why the aa.zip file is not being created?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The obvious place to start would be with the error message printed to stderr by the zip command.

Comment: That said, it would also be much, much saner to iterate over the splitfiles rather than hardcoding them and needing to modify the script if the size of your backup changes.

Comment: ...it would also be saner to use a compressor that doesn't try to also be an archiver, instead of using `zip` (which is both) **after** `tar`, which does archiving (but not compression) itself!

Comment: ...and even saner than that would be to do both archival _and_ compression *before* splitting, which will guarantee that your splitfiles are actually of identical size, and also make the compression more efficient (since the tables won't need to get rebuilt around the boundaries).